# GitHub Actions Fails to Recognize Successful Azure Container Instances Deployment

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

I'm running into an issue, when I deploy a docker container to Azure Container Instances.
The deployment is successful and the container is running on the Azure container Instances and works great. This isn't reflected in GitHub-Actions though, there this step in my workflow file is still running. This step runs for 30 mins and then fails, because of its length. This is the Error:

`Error: Long running operation failed with error: "pulling image "***/***_celery@sha256:67a5f6b08d8d2ca11f9990a88b6d195c50623d11fd5fd90e2cc866f185f4bc";Successfully pulled image "***/***_celery@sha256:67a5f6b08d8d2ca11f9990a88b6d195c50623d141d5fd90e2cc866f185f4bc";Started container;Killing container with id a6e32d3618b10e8cd39e65222c528626d9f817b25675a361cf664e0f2b0cf9.;pulling image "***/***_celery@sha256:d98f340067dba7a356dcb4265f369f7168b32b00e377862499ecaabdafe0f2";Successfully pulled image "***/***_celery@sha256:d98f340067dba7a356dcb4265f369f7168b320e54377862499ecaabdafe0f2";Started container;pulling image "***/***_celery@sha256:3d40fbf58a48a147543b35e701c25f2d4f284100f1203e26fd70540a7fe85e";Successfully pulled image "***/***_celery@sha256:3d40fbf58a48a147543b35e701c25f2d4f284100f1df3e26fd70540a7fe85e";Started container;Subscription deployment didn't reach a successful provisioning state after '00:30:00'.".`

As I said, everything works fine on Azure, only the Action is marked as failed.

I start my container like this:
`exec supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`

This is the part of my workflow:
`

- name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
  uses: azure/login@v1
  with:
  creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

  ```
    name: 'Deploy celery to Azure Container Instances'
    uses: 'azure/aci-deploy@v1'
    with:
    resource-group: myResourceGroup
    dns-name-label: my-dns-name-label
    image: myregistry/myimage:${{ github.sha }}
    registry-login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
    registry-username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
    registry-password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
    name: myContainerName
    location:
    restart-policy: 'Never'`
  ```

If you have any questions or need more information, let me know.

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

I tried using exit 1 at the end of the entrypoint script. This makes it successful in the Github actions, even though the code is 1, very weird.